# Notes on dga's with a look towards Rational Homotopy Theory?

Tags: homotopy-theory, graded-modules

What is the best set of notes that give an introduction to differential graded algebras, preferably with ample examples and calculations, for someone that is ultimately interested in doing calculations with Sullivan algebras?

If you are familiar, I am starting to work through Rational Homotopy Theory by Yves Felix et al. and looking for something to serve as a companion (at least on the algebraic side of things).

Comment: Not quite a direct answer to your question, but I found it *really* helpful to have some experience with simplicial sets and model categories before jumping into Felix/Halperin/Thomas. When studying the "homotopy theory" of cdgas, a lot of the argumentation is simplified if you phrase things in terms of a model structure on the category of cdgas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A useful introduction (but short) is Kathryn Hess' notes for a minicourse:

http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/hess_ratlhtpy.pdf

but you probably know of that already. If you can find a copy, Halperin's old lecture notes are very useful. They were distributed from Lille but that is quite a time ago so they may be difficult to obtain. If you read French then the Springer lecture notes by Tanré are useful as well. (Note also that there will be a Workshop in Ottawa this coming May, with I presume some introductory lectures.)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the workshop!

Comment: I think I figured out things actually, but this answer can be a good reference for others.  The notes by Hess I knew of but hadn't looked through.